# Windows Storage Pool stuck at "Starting, OK" after rebooting for patches

Tags: windows-server-2019, storage-spaces

After rebooting for patches this week, my main storage pool is not showing up in Server Manger.

- no drives were removed
- all drives are visible in Device Manager
- no drive errors are reported
- shutdown was clean

**Get-PhysicalDisk** shows all drives in the pool with operational status of "Starting, OK"

[Storage Pool not Visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glf98.png)

```
DeviceId FriendlyName             SerialNumber                 MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
-------- ------------             ------------                 --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
16       ATA MTFDDAK128MBF-1A     1547112458EE                 SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 119.24 GB
15       ATA MTFDDAK128MBF-1A     1547112458AB                 SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 119.24 GB
0        HGST HUSMR1625ASS201     0PY194TA                     SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 232.89 GB
9        HITACHI H7230AS60SUN3.0T 001232R05P3D        YVG05P3D HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
13       HITACHI HUS72303CLAR3000 YHHGXVHA                     HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
14       HITACHI HUS72303CLAR3000 YXGSZPPK                     HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
11       HITACHI HUS72303CLAR3000 YVG9G7NK                     HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
10       HITACHI HUS72303CLAR3000 YVG9ET5K                     HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
2        HITACHI HUS72303CLAR3000 YXGT1GKK                     HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
12       HITACHI HUS72303CLAR3000 YVG063ND                     HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
6        IBM-XIV ST33000650SS  B1 Z293R4LD00009301VGCB         HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
5        IBM-XIV ST33000650SS  B1 Z295YDHM0000C323AEQK         HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
8        IBM-XIV ST33000650SS  B1 Z293QSAZ0000C248316H         HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
7        IBM-XIV ST33000650SS  B1 Z293P9BA00009247FY49         HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       2.73 TB
1        WD WD4001FYYG-01SL3      WMC1F1321979                 HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       3.64 TB
3        WD WD4001FYYG-01SL3      WMC1F0D3SK64                 HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       3.64 TB
4        WD WD4001FYYG-01SL3      WMC1F1554231                 HDD       False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown       3.64 TB
```

All drives show up in the Primordial pool:

```
>Get-StoragePool

FriendlyName OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsPrimordial IsReadOnly      Size AllocatedSize
------------ ----------------- ------------ ------------ ----------      ---- -------------
Primordial   OK                Healthy      True         False        41.4 TB      41.17 TB
SSDs         OK                Healthy      False        False      237.45 GB      235.5 GB
```

[All drives connected and visible in device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJowH.png)

[No drive errors reported.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUERb.png)

Are there any tools from Microsoft to resolve whatever has happened?  or is time to restore from last backup and loose what wasn't backed-up?

Comment: hey Buddies did you solve the problem? we have the same problem here.

Comment: I had to restore from backups.   I also used "ReclaiMe Strorage Spaces Recovery" to (partially) recover some of the newest non-backed-up data from the pool.

I then switched to StableBit Drive Pool - which has worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Please verfiy that after the update if any other changes made on the paths to the storage 
Switches. 
 Also verify that OS level changes you made are still compatible with code level on the XIV. 
 https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/support/storage/ssic/interoperability.wss

Also update to the lastest XIV HAK 
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/STZSWD_11.5.4/hsg/hsg_hak_kcwelcome_xsa.html

Also review documentation on this site that may assist
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/STJTAG/landing/xiv_kcwelcomepage.html